Jetpack Compose: how to set focus color separate from ripple color
We use a dark ripple color for most of our controls, which gives us a dark grey ripple effect AND dark grey focused state.
But we also use a custom "border-style" focused state for controls.  In this case, we want the ripple effect to still be a dark grey (or whatever color we set), but we don't want that color to come up in the focused state.
For example using this Modifier
    .border(
        width = 1.dp,
        shape = shape,
        color =
        if (interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState().value)
            Color.Black
        else
            Color.Transparent
    )
    .clickable(
        enabled = true,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = ripple(true, Dp.Unspecified, Color.Black),
        onClick = onClick,
        role = role
    )

we get the correct border in the focused state, but it takes in the Color.Black from the ripple effect and uses that in the focused state:
Screen shot of our button with wrong color:

Setting the ripple color to Color.Transparent allows our focused state to not have a background color when focused, but of course removes the click ripple animation.
Is there some way I can set the click ripple color and the focus background color independently?  Or alternatively, somehow "filter" the interactionSource being sent to .clickable() so it passes through click events but not focus events?

you can override the compositionLocal, and set the focus state with an alpha 0f
LocalRippleConfiguration provides RippleConfiguration(
     rippleAlpha = RippleDefaults.RippleAlpha
)

https://medium.com/@Syex/disabling-the-focus-indicator-on-iconbuttons-or-any-other-composable-that-uses-a-ripple-indicator-39751e8ab19e

